# Same content, served differently depending on the subdomain

Tags: asp.net, azure

Using Azure and C# and .Net, would it be possible to serve the same page (as index.html) while changing some of the contents of the page?

This is for individuals, hairdressers for example, who have basically the same webpage content. The content on the page would change to reflect the name displayed on the page and the e-mail.

So, for example, maria.wonderhair.com would show the same text as stefanie.wonderhair.com, the only changes would be some elements, like the title page and the name of the hairdresser, based on the subdomain.

It could also have some other dynamic content, based on the domain, like phone and e-mail. This data should be also stored in Azure, as a simple NoSQL database.

Would that be possible to achieve, without the need to configure DNS entries for every site/individual?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Hussein Al Kazwini` for the MSdoc to configure the DNS to use a [wildcard subdomain](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/frontdoor/front-door-wildcard-domain.md).

It is possible to serve the same page with some dynamic changes depending on the subdomain using Azure and .Net.

One way to do this is by using Azure Functions and Azure Cosmos DB.

You can create an Azure Function that receives the HTTP request and extracts the subdomain from the request URL. Based on the subdomain, the function can retrieve the hairdresser's name, email, phone number, and other dynamic content from the Cosmos DB.

The function can then use this data to generate a response that includes the same page content with some dynamic changes. You can use templating engines like Razor or Handlebars to make the content dynamic and easily configurable.

To avoid the need to configure DNS entries for every site/individual, you can use wildcard DNS to route all subdomains to the same endpoint. This means that any subdomain under the wonderhair.com domain will be directed to the same Azure Function.

Set up a Cosmos DB instance to store the hairdresser data. You can use the Azure Portal or Azure CLI to create the database, container, and items.

1. Create a container called "hairdressers" with items for each hairdresser, containing their name, email, and phone number.
2. Create an Azure Function to handle the HTTP requests. You can use the Azure Portal or Visual Studio to create a new Azure Function project with an HTTP trigger. The function should extract the subdomain from the request URL and use it to retrieve the data for the hairdresser from the Cosmos DB.

Using `C#` to extract the subdomain from the request URL.

```
string subdomain = req.Headers["Host"].ToString().Split('.')[0];
```

Use a templating engine to generate the `HTML` for the page. You can use `Razor`, Handlebars, or another templating engine to make the content dynamic.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>@Model.Name - Wonder Hair</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to @Model.Name's Wonder Hair salon!</h1>
    <p>Email: @Model.Email</p>
    <p>Phone: @Model.Phone</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you have the hairdresser data and the generated HTML, you can return it as the response to the HTTP request.

```
return new ContentResult {
    ContentType = "text/html",
    Content = generatedHtml
};
```

Configure the DNS to use a wildcard subdomain. You can configure the DNS for the `wonderhair.com` domain to use a wildcard subdomain, such as *.wonderhair.com. This will route all subdomains to the same Azure Function, allowing you to serve the same content with dynamic changes based on the subdomain.